# ChromeOS PWA Debugging: "Failed to obtain app data, trying to run the app anyway"

Tags: progressive-web-apps, google-chrome-app

[I've built a PWA](https://supermeet-ng-dev.ey.r.appspot.com/) (link is if you'd like to replicate my issue and probably not representative of the final product). It runs fine both on my Macbook and on a Chromebase in a regular session. I can install it and everything is fine; no errors. Since the idea is to run it on digital signage tablets equipped with ChromeOS I've assigned a Chrome Enterprise upgrade license to a Chromebase for testing and deployed my app to it (press "Add by URL" [here](https://admin.google.com/ac/chrome/apps/kiosk) and set it to install and auto-launch).

But whenever the Chromebase starts up in kiosk mode now, it tries to load the app, reports that it `Failed to obtain app data, trying to run the app anyway`, and doesn't display the name and logo of the app, almost as if it couldn't get the manifest. This happens every time the device boots into kiosk mode undisturbed. In the admin console, the *App Details* page is also blank. Past the splash screen, the app works as intended. I'd like to deliver an app that doesn't immediately worry its users by showing an error message.

Thuslywise:

1. I've tried locally debugging, both in regular Chrome, as an installed Chrome app, and in kiosk mode, but the error reliably just doesn't occur locally.
2. [I've tried generating ChromeOS logs](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3293821), which is what Google Support told me to do. The logs simply report `Autologin account in prefs: https://supermeet-ng-dev.ey.r.appspot.com/` and `PublicSession autologin found:` for the local `web-kiosk-app` user.
3. I also tried some shortcuts (F12, Ctrl-Alt-I/S/K) on the keyboard attached to the Chromebase when in kiosk mode. However, the dev console etc seem to be disabled.
4. I also tried somehow getting onto the Chromebase remotely. I couldn't find any way other than Chrome remote desktop, which didn't work and doesn't seem promising given the local keyboard does nothing anyway.

So now I'm stuck since the error occurs only on the target device which seems to be quite locked down. What am I doing wrong?